# AngularJS and PHP - Notice: Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a simple `PATCH` http request from `AngularJS` to `PHP` and I'm getting the error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$todoName` in my console. Here are the codes:

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="UpdateTodoController">
<div class="input-field col s12" ng-repeat="t in todo">
      <input id="{{ t.id }}" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="todoName">
      <label class="active" for="{{ t.id }}">{{ t.name }}</label>
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="updateTodo(t.id)">Update
      </button>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function UpdateTodoController($http, $scope, $routeParams, $location) {


    $scope.updateTodo = function(todoId) {

        var req = {
         method: 'PATCH',
         url: 'app/endpoints/update-todo.php',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         },
         data: { 
            todoName: $scope.todoName,
            todoId: todoId
            }
        }

        $http(req)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            $location.url('/');
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

}
```

**update-todo.php**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$todoId = $data->todoId;
$todoName = $data->todoName;

$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE todo_list SET name=? WHERE id=?");
$statement->execute(array($todoName, $todoId));
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results);
```

It updates the specific field with the id but gives a `NULL` value. Am I missing something here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending data `form-urlencoded` but trying to use `json_decode` on it.

Remove the `Content-Type` header from angular request.

`$http` default is to send `application/json`.

A simple test would be to return a dump of `$data` and inspect in browser dev tools

Comment: Still getting the same but will try harder.

Comment: any special reason using PATCH? Have you tried POST or PUT?

Comment: Ah, I just want to update a record. Should I just use a POST instead?

Comment: PUT is most common for update in REST api's...also have you inspected actual request in dev tools to see what is actually sent?

Comment: Oh, PUT yes. Sorry. Nothing is being sent.. but I did the same thing on my POST, DELETE and it works.

Comment: nothing sent doesn't make sense...however should note that you are breaking the golden rule of not using object in `ng-model`

Comment: When I echo json_encode($data); and console.log(response) in my js, this is the console output http://imgur.com/ntuVMRG

Comment: but did you inspect the actual request inside browser dev tools? Have you tried logging data before sending it?? Browser dev tools are powerful....need to use them

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an undefined value of the $scope.todoName

Comment: shouldn't todoname be from each `todo` not one master? If so fix `ng-model` and pass whole object `t` to function and send `t` to server